# How to clear absolute positioned items on window resize?

Tags: html, css, window-resize

So by default, an absolute positioned div will fall out of view if the window is resized, but only the left side of the div. Is it possible to achieve the same effect to the right?

What I mean can be found here: http://diabetes.connectionsquad.com

If you resize the browser window to anything below 1010px you'll notice the left side of the navbar disappears, but if you scroll right, the right side of the nav bar stays in position.

Basically I have content div that is set to 1000px. My navbar is 1050 and it is centered in that content div with absolute position, so it hangs over the content div 25px on each side. When the browser size falls below 1050px, I want that 25px area to collapse and not be visible. By default browsers do this on the left, but not the right.

Can you clear the right side the same way you can clear the left? I tried researching it, but I got a bunch of junk because the search terms get skewed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the problem on Chrome. However, you're not setting `top` or `left`, it defaults to 0,0 for top and left, so it is attached to the top left corner of its relative parent. If you want it to be attached to the top right, you can give it

```
right: 0;
top: 0; /* Don't need this, it's the default;
```

Answer (score 0):

By "out of view", I am taking it you mean out of *your* set content width.

Have a look at negative positioning. **left:-20px; right:-20px**

```
 <style type="text/css">
   div { position:absolute; left:-20px; right:-20px }
 </style>
```

Hope helps,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Your layout doesn't require any absolute positioning, and it will give you monster headaches.

Rather than using a fixed width div in the center, you can do an outer margin or outer padding which is flexible.

```
/*Mobile*/
.outermargin {padding:0% 0% }

    /*Screen*/
    @media only screen
    and (min-width : 700px) {
        .outermargin { padding: 0% 7%; }
    }
    @media only screen
    and (min-width : 1400px) {
        .outermargin { padding: 0% 20%; }
    }
```

Use margin or padding depending on your needs... This CSS structure is one way to be more fluid and easier once you are used to it.

Or you could have centered it all using something like:

```
    #mycontainer { 
       margin: 0 auto; max-width:30em; }
```